# Compare string from array and if duplicate string available then append Incremented number to the duplicate string when creating a record

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to create a record but I have to check whether in the given list record with same name is available or not if available then append with incremented number. Below is the given list.

```
let listOfValues = [
{
  name: "Peter",
  age: 25
},
{
  name: "Paul",
  age: 35
},
{
  name: "Paul-1",
  age: 35
},
{
  name: "Dom",
  age: 28
}
```

]

And, I am creating a record as below:

```
  let requestBody = {
   name: "Paul",
   age: 28
  }
```

Now, I want to compare name from requestBody with the given list. Suppose, Paul is already available then it will check if Paul-1 is also available then it should increment with one number like Paul-2. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not React related. Please don't use irrelevant tags. Did you look at available Array methods yet? Like find()?

Comment: I have edited my tags, Yes, I have looked at find method but it is creating Paul-1 again even if it is already there.

Comment: Then you need to show us your code

Answer (score 0):

**Generic Solution**

- Generate a Regex to check a string that starts with the name in the `requestBody`.
- Filter down the list by searching for the names matching the Regex.
- You should split the names on `"-"` and return the index from the name.
- Sort the index list so that the largest index is at the end of the list.
- Check length of the list filtered out, if its zero, you can directly push.
- If its one you can push the element by appending 1 to the name.
- If its greater than one increment the last index and append it to name and push.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
let listOfValues = [
  { name: "Peter", age: 25 },
  { name: "Paul", age: 35 },
  { name: "Paul-1", age: 35 },
  { name: "Dom", age: 28 }
];

let requestBody = {
  name: "Paul",
  age: 28
}
const regex = new RegExp('^' + requestBody.name.split('-')[0], 'i');
const existingList = listOfValues.filter((item) => item.name.match(regex)).map((item) => +item.name.split('-')[1]).sort((a, b) => a - b);
if (existingList.length > 0) {
  const finalIndex = existingList[existingList.length - 1];
  listOfValues.push({ name: finalIndex ? `${requestBody.name.split('-')[0]}-${(finalIndex + 1)}` : `${requestBody.name}-1`, age: requestBody.age });
} else {
  listOfValues.push(requestBody);
}
console.log(listOfValues);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time @nitheesh. This is perfect solution but there is one problem when we create a request body. let requestBody = {
  name: "Paul-1",
  age: 28
}. Then it returns name as "Paul-1-2". But, I need "Paul-2" as Paul is already present in the list then Paul-1 is also there.

Comment: @MrityunjayYadav Updated the answer, please check

Comment: Please approve this answer and close the thread.

Comment: There is one more scenario, suppose { name: "Paul-2", age: 25 } is already there and when we create a request body, let requestBody = { name: "Paul-1", age: 28 }. Then it returns name as "Paul-2" even it is already present in the list. Expected should be it returns "Paul-1" .

Comment: Tested the code with the provided scenario, the output displays the entry ` { name: "Paul-1", age: 28 }` correctly in this scenario. Please test it correctly

Comment: Sorry, did mistake in above comment it should return "Paul-3" not "Paul-1". let listOfValues = [
  { name: "Paul", age: 35 },
  { name: "Paul-1", age: 15 },
  { name: "Paul-2", age: 29 }
]; Check for this, If you send requestBody = { name: "Paul-1", age: 28 }. Then it should be "Paul-3" because Paul-1 and Paul-2 are already present.

Comment: @MrityunjayYadav Updated the answer, please check. Also please not this is only a way of implementation. I have already built the core logic for your implementation. Please try to update the solution your own to match more test scenarions, rather than asking in comment to update the solution. Please approve this answer and close this thread.